# pyenv and anaconda issue with 'export PATH'

Tags: python, anaconda, pyenv

I have both [pyenv+virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) and [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) installed in my system, to manage virtual enviroments.

My .zshrc file looks like this:

```
# Load pyenv automatically:
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

In a given folder I set up a local `pyenv` virtual environment with

```
$ pyenv local test-env
```

Listing the `pyenv` virtual-envs within that folder results in:

```
$ pyenv versions
system
2.7.12
2.7.12/envs/test-env
* test-env (set by /home/<path>/.python-version)
```

But when I load python instead of opening a session with Python v2.7.12 (as one would expect since the `pyenv` virtual environment is loaded), I get:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So obviously the Anaconda platform is getting in between my `pyenv` virtual environment. Listing the `conda` environments shows:

```
$ conda-env list
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /home/<user>/anaconda3
```

If I comment out the `export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` line, `pyenv` works as expected.

Is there any way to maintain both these managers without conflicting with each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was apparently buried in point 3 of the pyenv instructions [Basic GitHub Checkout](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#basic-github-checkout):

> Please make sure `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` is placed toward the end of the shell configuration file since it manipulates `PATH` during the initialization

So the solution was to move that line to the end of the `.zshrc` file, like so:

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Load pyenv automatically:
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```